# Concurrency C#, Task<T> vs TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

Is there any diffrences between these two samples of code? They seem to work the same.
Sample 1:

```
Task<int> task = Task.Run(() =>      
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Foo");
                Thread.Sleep(6000);
                return 2137;
            });
Console.WriteLine("something...");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
Console.WriteLine("something again...");
Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
Console.WriteLine("nothing");
```

Sample 2:

```
new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Foo");
                Thread.Sleep(6000);
                tcs.SetResult(2137);
            })
{ IsBackground = true }.Start();
Console.WriteLine("something...");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
Task<int> task = tcs.Task;
Console.WriteLine("something again...");
Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
Console.WriteLine("nothing");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they both run code on different thread, but where that code executes will be different:

[`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) :

Queues the specified work to run on the [**thread pool**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.8) and returns a proxy for the task returned by function.

`new Thread(...).Start()`:

Sets a **new** thread to `ThreadState.Running`. The thread will generally be scheduled by the OS for immediate execution (outside of the ThreadPool). The [`IsBackground = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netframework-4.8) property means that the thread will not prevent the process from terminating, even if it is in mid-execution.